# Pointer alignment

Tags: c++, pointers

could anyone explain (by giving appropiate link for example) what does pointer alignment in c++ means?
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is an 'aligned pointer'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322926/what-exactly-is-an-aligned-pointer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good one too -  [Data_structure_alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)

> A memory address a, is said to be
>   n-byte aligned when n is a power of
>   two and a is a multiple of n bytes. In
>   this context a byte is the smallest
>   unit of memory access, i.e. each
>   memory address specifies a different
>   byte. An n-byte aligned address would
>   have log2 n least-significant zeros
>   when expressed in binary.

Comment: though I can't think of a processor that does this, why is it necessary that 'n is a power of 2'?  I can certainly imagine a processor align on 3 or 5 or 7 byte words, there must be domains that have this variety of number?

Answer (score 1):

In C, pointers align on machine word boundaries in structs.  So, even though you have:

```
typedef struct {
int a;
char c;
float f;
} example;
```

your `sizeof` will be different dependent upon your architecture. (each of 'a', 'c' and 'f' will be located on the aforementioned boundary and so will take potentially more space than just the size of an int, a character and a float.

Answer (score -1):

Why you should bother: In performance critical areas with lots of memory reads and writes you can gain a lot of additional performance by minding propery pointer alignment. This is even more true when you are planning to use vector instructions such as MMX, SSE and the like.

You do not need to bother about it though when writing your regular code. Only once you have identified a bottleneck that has to do with lots memory access operations you should start to investigate this further.

Comment: Why useless? Even the first hit provides an answer to the question in this thread.