# Casting memory into a struct pointer

Tags: c, struct, casting

When I do something like:

```
struct my_struct {
    uint32_t n;
    double   d;
    uint64_t *ptr;
    size_t   val;
};

struct my_struct a;
```

and in a function:

```
void a_func(struct my_struct *a) {
    a = (struct my_struct *) [a memory location];
}
```

I do not get correct values in a;

but when I do something like:

```
void a_func(struct my_struct *a) {
    *a = *(struct my_struct *) [same memory location];
}
```

I get correct values in the struct;

Any reasonable explanation for this?

Comment: Changing a pointer does not change the memory it (used to) point at.

Comment: please provide compilable examples.

Comment: Btw: this `struct my_struct a {` shall be `struct my_struct {`.

Comment: If you do this, beware of alignment requirements. You could easily crash your program if your memory isn't aligned.

Comment: @Cornstalks Can you please give pointer to better understand this problem? #pragma bundling will help?

Comment: @aryan: I can't fit it all into a comment, so I'll give you some links (some of these talk about C++, but it's the same in C): 1) [Should I worry about the alignment during pointer casting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881487/should-i-worry-about-the-alignment-during-pointer-casting). 2) [What exactly is an 'aligned pointer'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322926/what-exactly-is-an-aligned-pointer). 3) [Data structure alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment). `#pragma` won't really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets look at three different cases:

1. Change pointer *locally*

   ```
   void foo(S *a) {
       a = p;
   }
   S* b;
   foo(b);
   ```

   `a` is a pointer and this function changes the pointer `a`. It does not change the object `a` is pointing to. It also does not change `b` or the object `b` is pointing to.
2. Change object pointed to

   ```
    void foo(S *a) {
        *a = *p;
    }
    S* b = ...;
    foo(b);
   ```

   `*a = *p` performs a deep copy. It copies the object pointed to by `p` over the object pointed to by `a`. As `b` points to the same object as `a`, `b` will also see these changes.
3. Get pointer for usage outside the function

   ```
    void foo(S **a) {
        *a = p;
    }
    S* b;
    foo(&b);
   ```

   Now the function `foo` accepts a pointer to a pointer. By writing `*a = p` we change the pointer pointed to by `a` to `p`. This can be used to retrieve the pointer `p` as `b` will be the same as `p` after the call to `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you call that function and then try to use the `a` parameter after the function returned, e.g.

```
a_func(a);
printf("a->n: %u", a->n);
```

In both cases, you pass the pointer `a` by value. Changing the pointer itself in `a_func()` will not be reflected outside of `a_func()`. Put another way, `a` inside of `a_func()` is a copy of `a` outside, so changes to the pointer will not reflected outside after returning.

Changing the memory a points to will be visible outside, though.

In the first case (without `*`), you assign `a` itself in `a_func()`. As just explained, the new value of `a` will be lost as soon as `a_func()` returns.

In the second case (with `*`), you copy the memory from `[a memory location]` the memory pointed to by `a`. This means, that the memory `a` points to has to be valid: either it has to be on the stack, or dynamically allocated on the heap. Passing an uninitialized `struct my_struct *` pointer will lead to crashes sooner or later.

Once you return, you can access the data copied via the `a` pointer you passed to `a_func()`.

Example for correctly using the copy version (with `*`) with a local variable `a`:

```
struct my_struct a;         // Allocate a my_struct object on the stack.
a_func(&a);                 // Copy data from [some memory location] into a.
printf("a.n: %u", a.n);     // Access and use the newly copied data in a.
```

Another correct version with `a` allocated on the heap:

```
// Allocate a my_struct object on the heap and make a point to that memory.
struct my_struct *a = malloc(sizeof(my_struct)); 
a_func(a);                  // Copy data from [some memory location] into a.
printf("a->n: %u", a->n);   // Access and use the newly copied data in a.
free(a);                    // Take care to free the allocated memory when finished!
```

A broken example:

```
struct my_struct *a;        // An uninitialized pointer!
a_func(a);                  // The memory location a points to is overwritten - BUG!
printf("a->n: %u", a->n);   // May still work but you corrupted your memory with
                            // the previous function call. This will lead to crashes!
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as trying to change an integer from 3 to 5 inside a function and then failing. Check the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func( int a ) {
    a = 5;
}

int main ( ) {
    int x = 3;
    func( x );
    printf( "%d", x );
    // prints 3 not 5

    return 0;
}
```

This is because, when you pass `x` variable into `func` here, you pass its value, that is `3`; `func` creates a variable named `a`, assigns it with the passed value `3`, assigns it again with the value `5`. No change has been made to `x` there, so `x` still is just `3`.

If you were to pass the address of `x` as a value to some other function that takes an address as an argument, then access the contents of that address and change it, then you'd be able to remotely change the `x`, as in the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void anotherfunc( int * a ) {  // a is an address-holding variable
    *a = 5;  // *a is the content of that address and we are changing it to 5
}

int main ( ) {
    int x = 3;
    func( &x );  // passing the address of the variable x
    printf( "%d", x );
    // prints 5 now

    return 0;
}
```

Same story for your case, only with one further step of referencing/dereferencing. If you want to make the first version work out, make changes similar to the following:

```
void a_func(struct my_struct ** a) {  // added an asterisk
    *a = (struct my_struct *) [a memory location];
}

// ...

int main( ) {
    // ...
    struct my_struct * x;
    a_func( &x );

    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

Here, the `a_func` takes the address of an address-holding variable (pointer) as an argument, and stores that inside a newly created variable called `a`, which is a variable that holds address to an address to a `struct my_struct`. Then it accesses the contents of the address `a` holds, assigns that with a memory location, and so on...